# Does the Android tag dispatcher handle the NDEF records synchronously or asynchronously?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, ndef

I read along several times the documentation from Android Developer website about the NFC tag dispatcher (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html), but I can't figure out how the Android tag dispatcher is handling multiple NDEF records when reading them.

The process is crystal clear when you have one record, but in the particular case of having several records, does the tag dispatcher map successively to the dedicated intents, waiting each time if a request for choose action is sent to the user? In other terms will it work synchronously or will it executes in parallel all the related intents?

My point is to know if I can, for instance with Android M, pass a first record with the Wi-Fi pairing information and then a second with a webpage avoiding in particular an error type no internet connection found if done asynchronously?

Another use case is to have an app launcher as first record with a second record acting as a parameter or a kind of argument for the launched app.

Of course I want to do that in native Android, with no third party app.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is rather simple: Android does not dispatch multiple NDEF records as multiple intents at all.

If a tag contains multiple NDEF records, Android will only evaluate the first NDEF record to form the data part of the intent that it will dispatch to notify apps about this tag. It is up to the app that receives that intent to then decide to process any of the other NDEF records.

The only exception to this is the Android Application Record. If such a record exists anywhere in the NDEF message (regardless of wheter it is the first one), that record will be used to deliver the NFC discovery intent to the application declared in the AAR. Still, the first record will be used to form the data part of the NFC discovery intent in that case.